# Using the command 'echo' how can I write a large amount of text and see the result?

Tags: command-line, echo

I have entered the command 'echo' then typed a large amount of text afterwards. After pressing enter an arrow appeared. How do I see the text that I have typed out?

Comment: What's the exact text you typed in ? Did you see `>` symbol after you've typed in your text ?

Comment: My guess is your text contained an apostrophe. Try entering another one `'` or a double quote `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're seeing an arrow then bash (the "shell" that interprets and executes your commands) thinks the command is not complete yet. In your case it's probably because you have unclosed quote characters (or some other unmatched delimiters) in your text.

Quotes, apostrophes and various other characters are handled in a special way by bash, and need to follow certain syntactic rules. They are not simply passed verbatim into the command you're trying to run, so if you want to pass these characters into the command without bash trying to interpret them, you'll need to "escape" them by preceding them with a backslash character (`\`).

Some of these characters are: `"':;(){}*#$!|\`.

So for example, instead of:

```
echo I'm Joe
```

Use:

```
echo I\'m Joe
```

To receive better help I suggest you update your question and include the command you're to execute, if you're fine with posting the text.

Comment: @TomScott If the question helped you please mark it as correct.